# Ethereum: low tx nonce or out of funds

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I started a private network with issuing the command:

```
geth --datadir="~/datastore/ethereum" --port 30303 --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr localhost --networkid 554433 --rpccorsdomain="*" --minerthreads "4" --mine --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --maxpeers 0 --nodiscover --unlock=0 --verbosity 4 --gasprice 100 --gpomin 0 --gpomax 0
```

Then I called a smartcontract. I saw that smartcontract never do anything.

I looked at log information, I always get the message.

```
removed tx (
TX(b1a52b1414eb7b957ce4688a5aad07745f3055b3d415ca55d94afa45549c5dac)
Contract: false
From: af8f853382b3b6db6ab7fa4f7df6f5329976988d
To: c51b59d444993f6d613b023bf8598b781752fc54
Nonce: 14
GasPrice: 0
GasLimit 90000
Value: 0
Data: 0xb0c8f9dc0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002e516d54704b727248594459794567466d6373434654647a4b6f3154575346595046594239334d696d38456d467764000000000000000000000000000000000000
V: 0x1b
R: 0x97acff26b4ac5727ade4c7a37a69c9ac6c53d3d02530091b81352804566719cd
S: 0xe4b9c8e587a50e8d3b371423913da5bf7be019e5ea78991ad8b089e8802128f
Hex: f8e50e8083015f9094c51b59d444993f6d613b023bf8598b781752fc5480b884b0c8f9dc0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002e516d54704b727248594459794567466d6373434654647a4b6f3154575346595046594239334d696d38456d4677640000000000000000000000000000000000001ba097acff26b4ac5727ade4c7a37a69c9ac6c53d3d02530091b81352804566719cda00e4b9c8e587a50e8d3b371423913da5bf7be019e5ea78991ad8b089e8802128f
) from pool: low tx nonce or out of funds
```

Could you please give me an advice?

Comment: I think you should post your contract code and the transaction code which is trying to create the contract.  On top of that, did you check that the account creating the contract actually has funds?

Answer (score 1):

The error code is pretty straight forward. Your issue is either

- too low transaction nonce
- or the sender account has insufficient funds

I see you are setting the gas price to 0, however, I think the geth client still checks if there are funds available. So two things you can do:

- check if `0xaf8f853382b3b6db6ab7fa4f7df6f5329976988d` has some funds on it, if not put like 1 testnet Ether on it and try again.
- check the transaction count on that account with [web3.eth.getTransactionCount(accountAddress)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2545/87), if the nonce is too low, try to increment it by 1 until it works.

See also [this question on Ethereum Stack Exchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2601/87).

Answer (score 0):

I had such issue with "too low transaction nonce". It happened when I tried a second ERC20 token transfer while first one was still not completed (less than X confirmations).

once the first one finished, I could do the second one without issues.